# empty allure-report. allure-results directory has all results , but data's allure-report directory (test-cases, attachment) is empty

Tags: docker, selenium, jenkins, report, allure

prompt with a solution to receive an empty Allure-report on a remote machine. The results themselves are generated and added to the allure-results folder, but for some reason allure-report is displayed empty, that is, it does not add data to the allure-report / data / test-cases folder, what might be wrong?

allure-results path: `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-project/allure-results`

```
[my-project] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation/Allure_Commandline/bin/allure generate /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-project/allure-results -c -o /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-project/allure-report
Report successfully generated to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-project/allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

and also my DockerFile

```
FROM python:latest as python3
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome
USER root
WORKDIR /my-projest
ADD . /my-projest
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --user -r requirements.txt
RUN sudo pip3 install pytest
RUN ["pytest", "tests/GUI/test_main_page.py", "-s", "-v", "--alluredir=allure-results"]
```

In Jenkins I have shell command

```
IMAGE_NAME="myimage"
CONTAINER_NAME="mycontainer"




echo "Check current working directory"
WORKSPACE=`pwd`
pwd

echo "Build docker image and run container"
docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
docker run -d --name $CONTAINER_NAME $IMAGE_NAME

echo "Copy allure-results into Jenkins container"

docker cp $CONTAINER_NAME:my-project/allure-results allure-results

echo "Cleanup"
docker stop $CONTAINER_NAME
docker rm $CONTAINER_NAME
docker rmi $IMAGE_NAME
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZAZx.png)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem. In Jenkins Server was set the oldest version Allure Commandline("From Maven Central")>version 2.6.0 and I set the newest version 2.13.9 and hurray! the report shows the results

Comment: I am using 2.17.2 version .. but still my data/test_cases folder is empty.. i am generating with pytest, but when ran it with command line it works or simple python code with command in os.system() also working just when integrated with pytest it doesnt generate file... any idea?